# SQL: Expression order in SQL compare

Tags: sql

Is the expression order relevant in a compare statement?
For example:

```
select * from person where name = 'John'
```

and

```
select * from person where 'John' = name
```

Is there another reason other than readability to have the column first instead of the value?

Comment: No, it is not relevant.

Comment: Is there any reason other than lack of readability to put the value first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SQL database systems will have sections of their documentation that explicitly describe their syntax. I'll use SQL Servers [Search Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)<sup>1</sup>, since that's my most common reference:

> ```
> <search_condition> ::=  
>     MATCH(<graph_search_pattern>) | <search_condition_without_match> | <search_condition> AND <search_condition>
>
> <search_condition_without_match> ::= 
>     { [ NOT ] <predicate> | ( <search_condition_without_match> ) }   
>     [ { AND | OR } [ NOT ] { <predicate> | ( <search_condition_without_match> ) } ]   
> [ ...n ]   
>   
> <predicate> ::=   
>     { expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } expression
> ```

Here, we can see that the items on both side of the `=` (as well as many other operators) are described as `expression` - that is, anything that can appear on the left can equally well appear on the right.

Compare this, for example, with `IN`<sup>2</sup>:

> ```
> | expression [ NOT ] IN ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ] )
> ```

where we can clearly see that what's allowed on the left and right are subtly different.

It's well worth, when you have question on syntax, to consult the relevant documentation for your database product. For standard SQL, as here, just about any product's documentation will do.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which in turn was reached from the documentation for [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

<sup>2</sup>Same page as `<predicate>`

Comment: Thank you for the insights Damien_The_Unbeliever!